Proving the convergence of $x_n = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \dots + \frac{1}{n!}$ using the Cauchy criterion
I'd be very grateful if you could answer this question:

Prove the convergence of the sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ where $$x_n = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \dots + \frac{1}{n!}$$ using the Cauchy criterion.

I argued as follows (but, I have my doubts).
Definition: $$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \ \exists n_\varepsilon \in \mathbb{N} | \forall n \geq n_\varepsilon,\forall p \in \mathbb{N}:\ |x_{n+p} - x_n| < \varepsilon.$$
$$|x_{n+p} - x_n|=|\sum_{k = n+1}^{n+p} \frac{1}{k!}| \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\dots+\frac{1}{(n+p)!} < \frac{1}{(n+1)!}*p.$$
Let $\varepsilon$ be an arbitrary positive number. Since $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{p}{(n+1)!}=0$, for this $\varepsilon$ there exists a $n_\varepsilon$ such that for any $\frac{p}{(n+1)!}<\varepsilon$ is true.
So, if $n>n_\varepsilon$ and $p \in \mathbb{N}$ then:
$$|x_{n+p} - x_n|<\frac{1}{(n+1)!}*p<\varepsilon.$$

I think it is better to post one problem at a time.

All right, I will

The last part of your estimate, $<\frac{1}{(n+p)!}*p$ should read as $<\frac{1}{(n+1)!}*p$ which is not helpfull. The usual esitimate is $<\frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+1)! 2}+\dots+\frac{1}{(n+1)! 2^{p-1}} $ which is $<\frac{1}{(n+1)!}(1+2^{-1}+\ldots+2^{-(p-1)}+\ldots)$ or $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}(\frac1{1-\frac12})$.

Good attempt, Setting $p=(n+2)!$ shows the argument does not work.

Why not compare with geometric series:
$$ \frac{1}{(n+1)!} + \frac{1}{(n+2)!} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(n+p)!}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left( 1+ \frac{1}{n+2} + \left(\frac{1}{n+2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n+3}\right) + \ldots + \prod_{i=2}^{p} \left(\frac{1}{n+i}\right) \right) $$
$$ < \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left( 1+ \frac{1}{n+2} + \left(\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^2 + \ldots + \left(\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^{p-1} \right) $$
$$ < \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+2}\right)^k = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+2}}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \frac{n+2}{n+1} < \frac{1}{(n+1)!} \frac{n+1}{n} = \frac{1}{n!n}. $$
This idea is not my own: it comes from Rudin's PMA.
